# How to enable debug of mysql plugin?

Tags: mysql, debugging

I am trying to get debug messages from ndb in mysql server.

The mysql is compiled in bld_debug mode/dir.

I start mysql with

```
mysqld --debug='d:t:i:o,/data/mysql/mysqld.trace'
```

yet the file is empty, and remains empty. I get no output from any DBUG macro in the ndb code (but printf() that I add are printed on stdout).

Please advise

Comment: it is possible that the trace file gets created, with data, and then overwritten (recreated). At one time I caught it with size!=0, but when I went to read the content it was empty again

Comment: When I latch a tail -fF /data/mysql/mysqld.trace I seetail: /data/mysql/mysqld.trace: file truncated
T@2: | info: pollEvents res: 0
tail: /data/mysql/mysqld.trace: file truncated
T@2: | info: pollEvents res: 0
tail: /data/mysql/mysqld.trace: file truncated
T@2: | info: pollEvents res: 0